# Reading the return value of a command where the output is captured

Tags: bash

Usually, when I want to know if a program succeded, I do something like this:

```
mycommand
RTV=$?
# check if RTV is 0
```

However, what if I want to capture the output of the command in a variable like this:

```
MYCOMMANDRES=$(mycommand)
RTV=$?
# check if RTV is 0
```

will $? still contain the return value of the `mycommand` process?

Comment: Yes. Just try it with a valid and invalid command to see the result in $?. Have you faced any problem ?

Comment: Consider reading about special parameters in bash: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html

Comment: @RachidK. I did but I wondered if it could be somehow altered by the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will. Note that this does not mean that a "mere assignment" does not modify the assigned value. For instance

```
false
x=5 
echo $?
```

outputs 0, because the assignment clears the status, but

```
x=$(printf 5;false)
echo $?
```

outputs 1.